# Change the datatable in Form1 from Form2 Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, forms, datatable

So i have this code in the form called `MyMenuForm`.

```
Public Class MyMenuForm

    Public Sub LoadForm(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        DataGrid.DataSource = DataGridTable
        DataGridTable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        DataGridTable.Columns.Add("Verison", GetType(String))
        DataGridTable.Columns.Add("Compile", GetType(Button))
        DataGridTable.Columns.Add("Location", GetType(String))
        DataGridTable.Columns.Add("CompileLoc", GetType(String))
    End Sub

    Public DataGridTable As DataTable

End Class
```

I want to be able to edit `DataGridTable` from a different form called `AddForm`.

```
Public Class AddForm

    Public Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
        MyMenuForm.DataGridTable.Rows.Add(NameBox(), VersionBox(), "Compile", LocationBox(), CompileBox())
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I click on the `AddButton` button, I receive the error

```
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how I can fix it? I have googled to the extent of my ability and have found no solution. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new module in your project then declare your datatable in there ..

```
Public DataGridTable As DataTable
```

Don't declare public in class form ..

So you can call in every form class ..

```
Public Class AddForm

    Public Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
        DataGridTable.Rows.Add(NameBox(), VersionBox(), "Compile", LocationBox(), CompileBox())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Is LoadForm executed correctly? It seems that you haven't instantiated a new DataTable. So DataGridTable is always Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated DataGridTable anywhere as far as I can, see, you have only declared it.
You are going to need a

```
DataGridTable = New DataTable
```

at some point, probably in the LoadForm sub

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [test project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9935281CD314F220!25986) I created for this example

Here's a little bit of explanation:

It's very important to pay attention to scope.  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is a very common error, one that usually indicates a need for some kind of architectural adjustment.

Here's the setup for the **MyMenuForm** class.  The DataTable is declared as a property of that class, so anybody who can access the class, can access that particular property.

```vb
Public Class MyMenuForm

    Public DataGridTable As New DataTable

    Private Sub LoadForm(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With DataGridTable.Columns
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Verison", GetType(String))
            .Add("Compile", GetType(Button))
            .Add("Location", GetType(String))
            .Add("CompileLoc", GetType(String))
        End With
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataGridTable
    End Sub

End Class
```

You'll also need to make sure that the `MyMenuForm` has been created before you try to add rows with the `AddForm` class.  In my case, I just added it as the startup form and opened up an add form on click

[image: Startup From]

In the **AddForm**, make sure you reference the `DataGridTable` property on the `MyMenuForm` class, like so:

```vb
Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    Dim row As DataRow = MyMenuForm.DataGridTable.NewRow()

    With row
        .Item("Name") = "TestName"
        .Item("Verison") = "TestVerison"
        .Item("Compile") = New Button
        .Item("Location") = "TestLocation"
        .Item("CompileLoc") = "TestCompileLoc"
    End With

    MyMenuForm.DataGridTable.Rows.Add(row)

End Sub
```